# Run hex file in qemu

Tags: qemu

I want to run an ARM hex file in qemu-2.9.1 compiled from source but I don't know what I have to do.
I spent very time to search but I didn't find any suitable answer.
I am using ubuntu installed in virtualbox.

Comment: Ubuntu, VirtualBox, qemu, ARM, hex file... That's a crazy mix of things, yet not explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you "spent time to search" mention what resources you have found and did not help you. It will help us exclude those and show that you actually did put time in your search.
have you looked at: https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#ARM-System-emulator

Comment: Thanks for answer. The exact thing I want to do is running an ARM hex file with qemu that compiled from source.

Comment: Most of information that I found was about running OS and some of them use KVM. I found that I have to use qemu in user mode and run qemu-arm (if not mistake) but I cant do that because I'm beginner in linux and qemu.